# How can I use loop over a list of strings and access a nested value in a dictionary using the values?

Tags: python, recursion, yaml, rules

I'm building a rules engine. I want to be able to say:

```
networking.domains.$.records.$.record: false
networking.domains.$.records.$.type: false
networking.domains.$.records.$.ttl: false
networking.domains.$.records.$.entries: false
networking.domains.$.records.$.entries.$: false
```

Then loop over a YAML file which looks like this

```
networking:
  domains:
    - something: hello
      records:
        - record:
          ttl:
          entries:
            - entry: 1.2.3.4
```

And determine if the YAML file complies with the rules I defined.

So the rule `networking.domains.$.records.$.record`, for example, is saying: look for `yaml['networking']['domains']` and for each item (`$`) check it has `records`, and for each item (`$`) in that key check each field there for a valid entry, etc.

There's probably a simple way of doing this, or an easier way to approach the problem. I do want the solution to simply work with new entries and data types I introduce to the YAML file. So it needs to be somewhat flexible.

EDIT v1:

I believe I've solved this with the following code, which seems to be working in most cases:

```
# This gets populated with bad keys as the rules are processed
badkeys = []


def parse_rules(rulesplit, rules, config):
    if rulesplit[0] == "$":
        parse_rules(rulesplit[1:], rules, config)

    if isinstance(config, list):
        for item in config:
            if isinstance(item, list):
                parse_rules(rulesplit, rules, item)

            if isinstance(item, dict):
                if rulesplit[0] not in item:
                    not_present(item, rulesplit[0], rules)

                if rulesplit[0] in item:
                    present(item[rulesplit[0]], rulesplit[0], rules)

    if isinstance(config, dict):
        if rulesplit[0] in badkeys:
            return

        if len(rulesplit) > 1 or rulesplit[0] == "$":
            parse_rules(rulesplit[1:], rules, config[rulesplit[0]])
            return

        if rulesplit[0] not in config:
            badkeys.append(rulesplit[0])
            not_present(config, rulesplit[0], rules)

        if rulesplit[0] in config:
            present(config[rulesplit[0]], rulesplit[0], rules)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What you have described here is a specification of your rule engine (with some parts missing, e.g. what `false` means). What you didn't describe is your problem. Mind that SO is here to help you when you encounter a specific problem while implementing this rule engine, but not for just writing code conforming to your specification. The title of the question hints at you having a specific problem, but you don't describe it: What's your list of strings and what's the nested value? To sum up: Please show the code you have and describe your problem based on it.

Comment: A general remark concerning checking a YAML file's structure: If you define classes that represent the data existing in the YAML file, you can load the YAML file into those classes which would both check for the correct structure and enable easier access, e.g. you could say `data.networking.domains[0].record` etc. This would avoid juggling with basic lists and dictionaries. The code that processes the YAML is already a, usually informal, specification of the YAML layout. Making it more explicit and using it for validation seems to be a better choice than bolting a disjoint rules engine on it.

Comment: @flyx great idea. I never realised that data classes were a thing, and using a library to parse YAML to data classes is a good idea. Thank you.